# How can I win the Monaco race in B-Spec?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I've tried to win the Monaco race in B-Spec (the old cars) several times, and the max I've obtained is third position.

I've used the Toyota 7, with a driver of level 24.

The Toyota 7 is upgraded to the max, the oil of the car has been cleaned, the wheels are "soft/competition", and the configuration of the car is the default.

How is it possible to get the gold?

Comment: Your question is rather broad.  Try narrowing it down to a question about improving specific strategies, like car choice or corners to try and overtake opponents.  Also, the resounding answer to "Is it possible" will be yes.

Comment: @MBraedley I think it's not broad. It's about 1 race, in a 1 mode (B-spec), in 1 circuit that is specially difficult. And I've added the data I have (the car and the driver). What data do you need to answer the question?

Comment: How about more information in general.  Are you able to tune the car, for instance.  If so, how is it currently tuned?  Your question is akin to "How do I beat boss X?" and can't be effectively answered.

Comment: @MBraedley The Toyota 7 is upgraded to the max, the oil of the car has been cleaned, the wheels are "soft/competition", and the configuration of the car is the default. If you need more information, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level your driver up a bit more and it should be a lot easier. I'd suggest trying it again when your driver is up to level 30.

Also, are you monitoring your driver and giving him instructions? Many B-spec races can be won by simply leaving the driver to get on with it, but Monaco is one where you'll need to constantly monitor your driver.

Changing the settings on the car should help a little - increase the downforce front and rear, and shorten the gearing a bit for better acceleration (but make sure the engine doesn't hit the rev limiter on the fastest parts of the circuit).